# CMake Visual Studio Debug build type has symbols disabled

Tags: visual-studio-2013, cmake

I'm generating all the default CMake build types Debug, MinSizeRel, Release, RelWithDebInfo. All of the configurations have "Generate Debug Info" set to NO.

[image: Project Properties]

Am I supposed to manually set it in CMake code? All this flag really does is append /DEBUG in the linked cmd-line, I would at least expect the Debug configuration to have this set.

Could these CMake settings influence improper flag generation?

```
# Detected Visual Studio build
elseif ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "MSVC")

    # enable all DS_WARNINGS
    set(DS_WARNINGS "/W4 /WX /EHsc")

    if("${DS_PLATFORM_NAME}" STREQUAL "x86")
        list(APPEND DS_EXT_LIBRAIRIES "portaudio_static_x86") 
        list(APPEND DS_EXT_LIBRAIRIES "KSGuid")

    else()
        message(FATAL_ERROR "64-bit build not supported.")
    endif()

endif()

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS   "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${DS_WARNINGS}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${DS_WARNINGS}")
```

Comment: I presume that's default (and, yeah, quite strange) `Debug build` property in `Visual Studio 2013`. According to this [MSDN source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsk896zz.aspx) setting `Generate Debug Info` to `Yes` should be enough. 

If not, also try those 4 other properties mentioned in the linked resource: `Debug Information Format` to C7 compatible (`/Z7` or `/Zi`), `Enable Incremental Linking` to `No`, `Optimization References` to `/OPT:REF` and `Enable COMDAT Folding` to `/OPT:ICF`.

Comment: ***Am I supposed to manually set it in CMake code?*** No. Debugging symbols should be enabled in Debug and RelWithDebInfo by default. I assume whatever project you are building is improperly resetting the compiler settings with their CMakeLists.txt ...

Comment: I guessed that the CMakeLists.txt was setting `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` or `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` without appending the previous flags. You are not doing that so I am not sure why this is happening. Did you mess with either of these in cmake-gui. Or even the config specific versions of these?

Comment: Both of them are empty in the CMake Gui, didn't touch them. I'll take a look at other projects to see if there's any hint.